# A query that can compare multiple columns in a row in one table, with all the data in one column of a second table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Table 1 has only 1 row but 3 columns. Table 2 has 2 columns but many rows. 
I want to find where there is 3 rows in Table 2 that have matching column 2, but each row's column 1 equals each of the columns in Table 1.

Example:

**Table 1**

| A | B | C |

**Table 2**

| A | 1 |

| A | 3 |

| B | 1 |

| B | 3 |

| C | 1 |

| C | 2 |

| C | 3 |

| D | 3 |

**Query Result:**

| 1 |

| 3 |

Both '1' and '3' are spit out because they both have a corresponding 'A', 'B', and 'C' in one of their column 1's.

Sorry for the formatting but I hope you understand. I'm doing this in Microsoft Access SQL, but I don't think that pertains to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you please give more context. What you want to do can be done, but I suspect there is a simpler approach to this problem, only there is not enough info on the problem to find another way.

Comment: What are the field (column) names for each table

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to do this if you have a small number of columns is by a few `unions`.  By selecting 1 column at a time from `Table1` and `union all` for all 3 columns you effectively change the format of that table to the same as `table2` and then you can just do an `inner join` at that point.

```
;WITH cteTransformTable1 AS (
    SELECT
        'A' as Col1
       ,[A] AS Col2
    FROM
       Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'B' as Col1
       ,[B] AS Col2
    FROM
       Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'C' as Col1
       ,[C] AS Col2
    FROM
       Table1
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteTransformTable1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
    AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2
```